# borrowed my Teffilin, fell asleep, nocturnal emission

Tags: tefilin, sleep, zav-zava

If somebody borrowed my Teffilin, and then accidentally fell asleep while wearing them, and during his sleep experienced a nocturnal emission, have my Teffilin become spiritually damaged at all?!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thank you for your thoughtful question!

Comment: Whoever voted to close, I don't see why this is considered Pesak Halacha, but ok...

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a problem in the slightest. Pleae ignore it and continue to serve God by wearing your Tefilin. If this hangup is preventing you from doing mitzvos in a positive manner, please consult a competent rabbi and/or mental health professional.

Rambam, laws of Tefilin, Mezuzah, and Sefer Torah 4:13

> וכל הטמאין, כולן חייבין בתפילין כטהורין
>
> The incontinent are exempted from wearing Tefilin, **but those who are ritually impure are all exactly as obligated to wear Tefilin as those who are ritually pure.**

Similarly in 10:8.

> כל הטמאים, אפילו נידות, ואפילו גויים--מותרין לאחוז ספר תורה, ולקרות בו:  שאין דברי תורה מקבלין טומאה.  והוא שלא יהיו ידיהם מטונפות, או מלוכלכות בטיט; אלא ירחצו ידיהם, ואחר כך ייגעו בו.
>
> *Anyone* ritually impure -- even a menstruant woman or a non-Jew -- is allowed to hold a Torah scroll and read it, **as the words of Torah cannot become impure.** This assumes their hands are not dirty or covered with mud -- if so, they should wash their hands, and then may touch it.

Comment: Tefillin actually can become impure, unlike a Torah scroll. See Keilim 18:8. See too Sukkah 26b regarding the laws of OP's case.

Comment: Thank you! Sukkah 26b actually reinforces the message here -- go ahead and wear the Tefilin the next day, no matter what happened.

Comment: @Abner I would like to relate a story which is reatled to the idea which Shalom brought out in his answer. There was a student in the Poneviz Yeshiva who came to the great Masgiach Rav Yechezkel Levenstein ZTL and said I have just been to Tel-Aviv, and I have unfortunately fallen into comitting a very great sin of immorality, What should I do now?  The Mashgiach answered him "Go up to the bais midrah and delve yourself into torah study for a few hours, Before the Yetzer Hara gets a chance to convince you that because of your heinous actions you are no longer worthy of studying the holy Torah!"